# NOT NULL constraint failed: complaint_complaint.resident_id

Tags: python, django

I am writing an app in which people can submit their complaints related to some issues.
After the form is submitted, it is supposed to redirect to the page where the details of the complaint are mentioned like area of the complaint, title, description etc.

But after the form is submitted, it throws IntegrityError.

I read about it and went through some of the solutions:

1. Someone suggested that I delete some past migrations and run them again. I cleared the migrations, ran them again and made some posts through the admin but it is throwing the same error.
2. Some posts suggest that null=True, blank=True should be added but I do not understand where they should be added in my case. I also don't want to add null=True, blank=True because I don't want any field to be left blank.

Below is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.
class Complaint(models.Model):
    """ Details of the complaint """
    resident = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    AREA = [('PL', 'Plumbing'), ('EL', 'Electricity'), ('CP', 'Carpenter'), ('CO', 'Construction'), ('DS', 'Disputes'), ('OT', 'Other'),]
    matter = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=AREA)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('comp_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Below is my urls.py which I created in my 'complaint':

Note - I used class-based views in my views.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import CompListView, CompDetailView, CompCreateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('comp/new/', CompCreateView.as_view(), name='comp_new'),
    path('comp/<int:pk>/', CompDetailView.as_view(), name='comp_detail'),
    path('', CompListView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

Some help will be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you did not set the `resident` when creating a `Complaint`.

Comment: I did the set the resident. It's a drop-down list in the admin and the resident is the superuser account for now.